# adding a sidebar to a single centered column

Tags: html, css

My layout has a single column on the homepage that's centred in the middle of the page.  The `.posts` class is contained in the `.home` class, which is contained in a `.wrap` class that has a max width of 800px. I wish to add a second narrow column or a side bar, for example of 120px, called the `.sidebar` class. If I set the .home class to have a maximum width of 600px and set the sidebar class to have a width of 120, it's still getting pushed to the bottom of the page, not next to the .home class.

Here's a demo on jsfiddle with the html and css from jekyll included http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/V4F6H/

How can I get the sidebar column next to the .home class?

HTML

```
  <div class="wrap">
      <a class="site-title" href="#">My Jekyll Blog</a>
    <nav class="site-nav"> 
      <div class="trigger">    
          <a class="page-link" href="http:google.com">blah blah</a>         
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="page-content">
    <div class="wrap">
       <div class="home">   
      <ul class="posts">  
      <li>
        <a class="post-link" href="#">This is a link to my post</a>
       <p></p>
      </li>
     </ul>
      </div>
     <div class="side-bar">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

key CSS

```
.wrap:before,
.wrap:after { content:""; display:table; }
.wrap:after { clear: both; }
.wrap {
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  zoom: 1;
}
.page-content {
  padding: 30px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}


.home h1 { margin-bottom: 25px; 
}
.home { max-width: 600px};
.sidebar{ width: 100px;}
```

Comment: float the `.home` div to the left and the `.sidebar` to the right.

Comment: @Paulie_D ok that worked if you write an answer I'll accept it or maybe close the question? was that too easy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Float the `.home` div to the left and the `.sidebar` to the right.

Unfortunately, your JSfiddle does not seem to have the full HTML and there is **way** too much CSS for a reduced case so I cannot make a demo.